# MarkdownSharp errors in a Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, markdownsharp

I was trying to play with MardownSharp in a Windows 8 app. But I'm getting errors in the Mardown.cs file. It doesn't have `System.Configuration` and `RegexOptions.Compiled`.

[image: Markdown.cs errors]

Comment: @w.brian Yes. I'm getting errors (different ones) in WPF too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here.

1. System.Configuration is not one of the [.NET namespaces available
   for Windows Store applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx).  The good news is that it seems
   to be used only in one of the overloaded constructors of the
   Markdown class:

   > public Markdown(bool loadOptionsFromConfigFile)

   Comment out that constructor (and the using statement). You could
   rewrite that constructor to make use of app local storage which
   would allow analogous functionality to a config file but not with
   quite the same implementation. I suspect you may not be using that
   overload anyway
2. The code makes heavy use of the [Compiled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) flag for regular
   expressions, which also isn't supported in this context.  You should
   be able to safely remove all references to that flag.

With those modifications I was able to at least compile the code, I didn't take it further.

Comment: Yesss! It works. Thanks a lot, Jim. I also had to remove `this(false)` from `public Markdown() : this(false)` since weren't using the constructor.

Comment: And could you please explain me a bit about the use of the constructor?

Comment: it looks like they give you a few options to initialize the Markdown object with some default ways to handles links, newlines, etc.  One of those constructors (the one that won't work) reads that information from an App.exe.config file, another alternative allows you pass that same info in via a MarkdownOptions class that you can populate in your code from whatever source you want - like perhaps the Settings flyout in Windows 8